# How to convert a plugin's config file for use with a newer cakephp version

Tags: plugins, config, cakephp-2.1

When looking for a way to provide a cakestrap application with Google Calendar, I came across an older post which mentioned this plugin:
http://www.neilcrookes.com/2009/09/27/get-google-analytics-data-in-your-cakephp/

While trying to add support for Google Calendar it turned out this plugin is not compatible with cakeStrap which I have to use.
I have allready refactored the models, views and controllers but I can't figure out how to convert the gdata-config so it can be used:

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Coniguration options for Gdata API
     */
    class GDATA_CONFIG {

      var $analytics = array(
        'datasource' => 'gdata',
        'driver' => 'analytics',
        'email' => '',
        'passwd' => '',
        'profileId' => '',
        'source' => 'CakePHP',
      );

      var $youtube = array(
        'datasource' => 'gdata',
        'driver' => 'youtube',
        'email' => '',
        'passwd' => '',
        'source' => 'CakePHP',
      );

        var $picasa = array(
            'datasource' => 'gdata',
            'driver' => 'picasa',
            'email' => '',
            'passwd' => '',
            'source' => 'CakePHP',
            'cache' => true,
            'cacheDuration' => '+1 hours'
        );

      var $calendar = array(
        'datasource' => 'gdata',
        'driver' => 'calendar',
        'email' => '',
        'passwd' => '',
        'source' => 'CakePHP',
      );

    }
    ?>
```

This is my first time working with cakePHP so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom configuration format (using PHP reader) is like:

```
<?php
$config = array('youtube' => 
    'datasource' => 'gdata',
    'driver' => 'youtube',
    'email' => '',
    'passwd' => '',
    'source' => 'CakePHP'
));
```

You can use `Configure::load('configuration_file_name.php')` to load configuration file and `Configuration::read('configuration_array_key')` to read configuration variables.

See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#configure-class for more information.